# Load jquery file inside a wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, accordion, shortcode

i׳m trying to create an accordion shortcode. 
when I load the scripts with wp_enqueue_script function it seams to work only for the jquery ui library but not the custom script

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
           $('#ks-accordion').accordion(); 
       }
);
```

Here is the full code:

```
// Container

function ks_accordion($atts, $content = null) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
    wp_enqueue_script('shortcode', get_template_directory_uri().'/functions/shortcodes/js/shortcodes.js');

    return '<div id="accordion">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'accordion', 'ks_accordion' );


// Section

function ks_accordion_section($atts, $content = null) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => 'My Title',
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<h6><a href="#">'.$title.'</a></h6><div><p>'.do_shortcode($content).'</p></div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'accordion_section', 'ks_accordion_section' );
```

This is the code I get in the front-end:

```
<div id="ks-accordion"><br>
  <h6><a href="#">Title</a></h6><div><p>Content</p></div><br>
  <h6><a href="#">Title1</a></h6><div><p>Content</p></div><br>
  <h6><a href="#">Title2</a></h6><div><p>Content</p></div><br>
</div>
```

Also I don't get why it creates these `<br>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is [loaded in `noConflict` mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) in WordPress. To use the dollar sign, we need the following

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) { // <---- put $ here
    $('#ks-accordion').accordion(); 
});
```

Much probably, `do_shortcode` is inserting those `<br>`, but it's just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script('shortcode', get_template_directory_uri().'/functions/shortcodes/js/shortcodes.js', array('jquery'));
```

Hope this helps!